# How do I add commands within a widget tree?

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter/dart, how do I add commands (for loops, if/then etc) within widget trees?

So let's say we have a tree

```
Scaffold(...)
```

How can I add command syntax in there. The only thing possible is ternary operators. (as far as I'm aware)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that inside `build()` like:

```
Widget build(context) {
  // use for loop or if else or anything you need
  return Scaffold(...);  
}
```

---

The better way to do is by creating a dedicated method like

```
void _doSomethingHere() {
 // use for, if-else etc
}
```

And use this method in button pressed like:

```
RaisedButton(onPressed: _doSomething)
```

---

If you want to perform some action before `build()`, you can override `initState()` like:

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  // use for, if-else 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that inside `initState()` if you are using `StatefulWidget`. Else do that inside `build()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why you can't use control structures(if-else) or loops(for,while,do-while) while creating your UI as a widget(-tree) is because of the way flutter tries to understand what UI are you trying to create.

The control structure `if` just accepts a block of code and executes it if the condition given to it satisfies.

```
if(condition)
{
//statment(s) to be executed
}
```

Whereas ternary operator simply replaces a particular line of code/value based on the condition given to it.

```
(condition)
?
value-or-code-to-replaced-if-the-condition-satifies
:
value-or-code-to-replaced-if-the-condition-does-not-satisfy;
```

Since we just return the UI, a widget tree to the build function using `return` keyword, adding control structures like `if` practically does not make any sense.